# Detection of anomal data in the text

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, speech-to-text

I work with texts where there is a dialogue between two people (a client and a call center employee, the beginning and end of each person’s phrase is not defined). My goal is to classify texts in which a call center employee names words from my list.
If the texts are manually marked up, can such a classification problem be solved?
Are there any tricks to solve this type of problem?

Sample data:
"hello hello my name is Sam Chin I'm calling for pizza delivery Okay now check your order wait a minute Sam"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do this, one approach is to use token-based matching. You can use this to easily find any "tokens" in the text, like names, places, or just plain words.

### Methodology

I'd recommend using [Rule-based Entity Recognition](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler) in spaCy. You'll define the "rules" of what the entity looks like, here's the example from the docs where we define the following patterns to find:

- An entity type of *Organization* and the word *Apple*
- An entity type of *Location* and the words *san* and *francisco*

Here's that in code ([live example](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler-usage)):

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = English()
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)

# These are the rules you define, look at the docs to see what your options are.
# You don't have to use the "label", you can just look for a "pattern" if you want.
patterns = [{"label": "ORG", "pattern": "Apple"},
            {"label": "GPE", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "san"}, {"LOWER": "francisco"}]}]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)

# The text you're searching through to find your patterns
doc = nlp("Apple is opening its first big office in San Francisco.")

# This prints out the matches
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
```

The output of this code is: `[('Apple', 'ORG'), ('San Francisco', 'GPE')]`

### Usage

Thankfully spaCy has some fantastic online tools for helping you write your patterns, I highly recommend you check these links out.

1. [Install spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage)
2. Evaluate if you should use [rules or a model](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#rules-vs-model) (I suggest rules but I could be wrong), and if you should use [token matcher or phrase matcher](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#matcher-vs-phrase-matcher)
3. Read the documentation to determine [how to write your patterns](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns-attributes)
4. Test your patterns using the [Live Rule-based Matcher Explorer](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher?text=hello%20hello%20my%20name%20is%20Sam%20Chin%2C%20I%27m%20calling%20for%20pizza%20delivery.%20Okay%20now%20check%20your%20order%2C%20wait%20a%20minute%20Sam.&model=en_core_web_sm&pattern=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A3%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22ENT_TYPE%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22PERSON%22%7D%5D%7D%5D)
5. Use the code snippet above or the code samples in the docs to see how to use your new patterns